# htaccess - bring index.html as default page for the first time

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I convert www.domain.com to domain.com/index.html as default.

for example if someone type www.domain.com it will redirect to www.domain.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R,L]
```

Comment: another question: Redirecting visitor to domain.con/index.html instate of domain.com is good or bad for SEO.

Comment: I don't know much about the specifics, but I'd imagine it's neutral since neither really has any content or keywords in the URI.

Comment: It would balance itself, making it essentially neutral – exposing technology (`.html`) would be a minus, but `/` and `/index.html` would be two links to the same content, so having an explicit redirect would be a bonus. Make sure to account as well for `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` as potentially different URLs.